# Create views with UI Pattern Views

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have views like this:

[image: Image views]

I want use module [UI Pattern Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/ui_patterns). I defined UI Pattern. File card.ui_patterns.yml with content

```
card:
  label: Three column fluid
  description: Three column fluid
  fields:
    image:
      type: render
      label: Image
      description: Media image.
      preview:
        theme: image
        uri: http://lorempixel.com/900/500/sports/1
        width: 150
        attributes: {}
    title:
      type: link
      label: Title
      description: Media title.
      preview:
        type: processed_text
        text: <a href="#">Etiam iaculis nunc ac metus</a>
        format: basic_html
```

and file pattern-card.html.twig have content:

```
<div class="card">
    {% if image is not empty %}
        <div class="card-image">
            {{ image }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{ title }}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how can use multil image style for this case. Any suggetion?

Comment: Well this is suppose to be solved easily by adding a row counter and your image again and then doing an if statement, but sadly there is a Drupal Bug  [Global: View Result Counter does not evaluate properly in IF statements](https://www.drupal.org/node/2764651)

Comment: @NoSssweat Sorry. Do you try use module UI Pattern Views?  I don't understand with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step:

- Install the UI Patterns Views module
- Insert the fields and map them to the UI Pattern fields

  - **Note:** You are mapping fields for the rows.

At this point, each piece of content should be rendered as a UI Pattern

Now, if you want to arrange the cards in a specific way (say, using Masonry), then you can do it in one of the following ways:

- Add a class to the entire view, say, `js-view-masonry` – you can then use this class in JavaScript to detect this view and apply the JS plugin that organizes the cards like you want.
- The other way will be to create a superpattern of the `card` pattern. Say, a `card_collection` pattern, with a field named `items`. Next, override the view's template, especially the part where the rows are rendered. Here, instead of displaying the rows, into the "card_collection" pattern.

Here's a [working example of the second method](https://jigarius.com/blog) using "card_collection". The blog list consists of 2 patterns. The "card" pattern and a pattern called "card collection" which wraps the cards.